# TextView : lineSpacingMultiplier and lineSpacingExtra applies to the last line too

Tags: android, textview

Ok, so everything is in the title : if we change the spacing between lines of a TextView with `lineSpacingMultiplier` or `lineSpacingExtra`, the last line of the TextView adds the extra too.

So the result is that we have spacing in the bottom of the view, as if we had a bottom padding. The text doesn't appear to be centered in the view, so the design of the layout is not sexy.

Is this really the correct behavior or a bug ? and is there any way to remove this spacing for the last line ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, I was using custom fonts that were making this behavior. So it's not a platform bug, or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,I was using

**android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"**

in my textview irrespective of the font used.

Removing this removed the linespacing from the last line of the textview